# How to import UTM coordinates into Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

I have some points in UTM coordinates that I'd like to import into Google Earth.  Google Earth is able to show UTM coordinates, but I have not found a way to import points or enter coordinates in a placemark's properties with UTM coordinates.

Is there any possibility to do this with just Google Earth or do I need to convert my data set externally?  I do have separate tools for coordinate conversion, but I'd like to spare the extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [**Plex.Mark!**](http://www.plexscape.com/plexmark.aspx) plugin.

Comment: Thanks, that's a start -- however, it only runs on Windows. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I use cs2cs from proj.4 so I can turn UTM to latitude and longitude. Here it is in DOS style but it is easier to use Unix style:

```
cs2cs -f "%%.6f" +proj=utm +zone=36 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs %file% >%file%.projected
```

I then use use GMT (generic mapping tools) to convert to KML.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't exactly what I was looking for.  My question was about entering coordinates directly, without going through external tools. Basically, I started out from what you did, and thought "this should be simpler"...